# Is there a way i can add Snowball filter while performing the query in elastic search.?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to perform word variant search in elastic search. I just indexed data in normal way. I need to search normally as well as well with word variants. After going through some posts, either snowball or porter stem filter can do the word variant search for me. But i needed them to trigger in query time when i select word variants. Please suggest me right way..

thank you..

Answer (score 1):

For a multi-match Query:

```
curl -XGET "http://my-server.com:9200/test/stack/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
           "query": "lazy",
           "fields": ["name","field"],
           "analyzer":"snowball"
        }
    }
}'
```

For a match Query:

```
curl -XGET "http://my-server.com:9200/test/stack/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "field": "lazy"
        },
        "analyzer":"snowball"
    }
}'
```

Hope you get the point